Blazor/Maui hybrid app using Entra ID. How?
I'm building an app that needs to run on Web, Android and iOS.
I'm hoping to write it most of it in Blazor using a Blazor Class Library hybrid design with Maui like this: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/9.0/MauiBlazorWeb
I also want to use Entra ID so that users can sign in with Google, Facebook etc. Like this: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/9.0/BlazorWebAppEntra
Can anyone tell me how put these two samples together into a basic example? Thanks.

It's a bit of a bore but asking for (sample) code is a close-reason here. Reword it as a "how to" question and it might be valid.

@HenkHolterman ...and even questions asking "how" tend to get downvoted and sometimes closed when they don't show any effort on the asker's side.
